# Can a radiogroup show a heading/title?

Tags: android

I've installed a radiogroup with three radio buttons on my app, but I want text to apear above it like it does with checkboxes and such. Can I reference the strings.xml file like this?

```
   <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/set_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/between_games_timer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="@string/sets_radio_group" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/one_set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/two_sets"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/three_sets"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RadioButton>            
    </RadioGroup>
```

Because when I run the app the three radio buttons appear without any text. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you considered just using a textview and positioning it next to the radio group..

Comment: add `android:text="xyz"` to each radio button

Comment: There is an example in the documentation but, typically, the documentation does not show how to reproduce the example.https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Answer (score 41):

Old question, but maybe my answer will help somebody.

One of the ways to add a header for all buttons, is to simply use `TextView` inside `RadioGroup`.

And of course, you can set text for each radio button.
You should use `android:text` property to set text for each of buttons. I used usual strings in examples below, but you should better extract your strings into Strings.xml

Here is an example:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/set_radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose one of three types:"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/onse_set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type one"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/two_sets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type two"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/three_sets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type three"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```